# How can I correct for using latent variables in mediation analysis?

Tags: mediation

I have 1 binary treatment and 7 latent factors as possible outcomes and would like to explore the association among them through a mediation analysis (using a structural Equation Model). Unfortunately, the number of items generating each of these latent factors is really huge (from 13 to 55, depending on the factor: 246 in total) making a full model (using observed variables) computationally unfeasible (I tried with 2 factors, one with 32 and the other with 54 items). I thought I could use factors from the Item-Response Theory model; however, there is an obvious error due to the fact that they are latent, thus only estimated. Is there a correction I can use for it, so that I can use such items for my mediation analysis? Alternatively, is there a way how I can reduce the number of items in my final analysis to make my model computationally feasible? I was thinking at something as described here:
([pdf](http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/0081175012470644))
but with a continuous latent variable, and in a mediation analysis setting.
Or should I give up on SEM's and look for something simpler?

Comment: Why do you think that the fact that they are latent is a problem?

Comment: Because latent factors are the results of an estimation process rather than observed. Otherwise I wouldn't understand why one should build a model by simultaneously creating the latent factors and exploring the relationship between treatment, mediator(s) and outcome(s) instead of always using a two-step procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a paper addressing this issue:

([pdf](http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/0013164415607618))

A two-stage model where first factor scores are calculated then used in a regression (in the way I was asking) is called factor-score regression and the fact that factor scores are estimated introduces a bias. The paper compares (among others) two methods to address this bias:  the bias avoiding method of Skrondal and Laake, and the bias correcting method of Croon.

Answer (score 0):

Factor scores do not have to introduce a bias but they do necessarily contain an arbitrary component, though with dozens of items the arbitrary component could be quite small(e.g., [Rigdon, Becker, & Sarstedt 2019](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00273171.2018.1535420?casa_token=HtWqanwknSwAAAAA:5uXKNaJk5akAogZ2sKxHZSlt08mkn1vyDWJuSrTWC0sc7Rig3qiyQUkorGMlbsTIYlGNPVJUOXG8)). The arbitrary component means that estimates will vary depending on exactly how the arbitrary component is chosen.

If your inability to estimate the factor model is not just a matter of sample size, you might consider Bollen's (e.g., [2019](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00273171.2018.1483224?casa_token=rYxmq_EjbFsAAAAA:BR43WOxXX482nYKYmB8vczOZRlNS9Ot-byX9pfUUF7yo3LnmzV-oz9gSt60Ti3rLr29uH0Gwn1w0)) Model-Implied Instrumental Variable (MIIVsem) method, using two stage least squares.